# Using CurrentRegion to select entire page

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that contains several pages and each page contains a name and some other info, i am using this code :

```
Dim Area as String
For i=1 to 10000
If worksheets(1).cells(i,4)=name then
Area=worksheets(1).cells(i,4).CurrentRegion.Address
End If
Next i
```

the code works, however it only selects the area near where the name is found, and i want it to select the entire page (there are several pages in the sheet) instead of the small area around the name, is there a way to do this with CurrentRegion? or perhaps is there another property i can use instead?

I've looked everywhere for an answer to a similar question and however no luck, thanks to all replies.

Comment: What do you mean by 'page' within the worksheets?

Comment: Sort of like page breaks between several sections in the same worksheet (kind of like the same concept of MSWord)

Comment: What do you want to do with the page that contains the name? Selecting a range and then doing something to the selection is inefficient. Far better to use the range directly within the property or method you want to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments show you know that page breaks will play a part in the answer.

The code below will display a print preview of the page on which range parsed in Name sits. If the sheet has more than one page, determined by `WS.HPageBreaks.Count`, then loop through the `HPageBreaks` while the `HPageBreak` row is less than the row of the parsed range name.

```
Sub PrintSheetContainingTarget(Name As String)
'assumes sheet containing Name has no VPageBreaks
'(i.e. sheet is one printed page wide)
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Break As HPageBreak
Dim Page As Long
    Page = 1 'initialise Page in case only one page on sheet
    Set WS = Range(Name).Worksheet
    If WS.HPageBreaks.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Break In WS.HPageBreaks
            If Break.Location.Row < Range(Name).Row Then
                Page = Page + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'display print preview of Page
    WS.PrintOut Page, Page, 1, True
End Sub

Sub PrintWrapper()
    Call PrintSheetContainingTarget("Target")
End Sub
```

I'm assuming you want to print the page containing `Name` but if you want to do something else replace `WS.PrintOut Page, Page, 1, True` with code to achieve your objective.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to

```
If worksheets(1).cells(i,4)=name then
    Area = WorkSheets(1).Name & "!" & "A1:XFD1048576"
    ' You may modify this line to dynamically get max rows @ 65k for Excel 2003, etc.
End If
```

Comment: That code will only select static pages, i kind of need something that depends on page breaks instead of a static address since the pages dimension will be changing.

Comment: How about trying `Area = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea`

Comment: Still no luck, I've found something on the Microsoft website concerning page break properties, i will try working with it, thanks for your answers and time anyway mate, much appreciated!